# Assigning contiguous pseudo row numbers to results returned by SELECT

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We have a table with an AUTO_INCREMENT, INT UNSIGNED index field.  Over time entries have been deleted from the table, creating "holes" in table.  In the past we have copied entries from our table to another table, without the index field, dropped the former table and renamed the latter to the former.

Of late we have resorted to this scheme:

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SELECT *, (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS pseudo_row_num FROM myTable;
```

This is working quite well except that we would like the pseudo row number to be shown as the first column.

The following gives a MySQL syntax error:

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS pseudo_row_num, * FROM myTable;
```

Comment: note that in mysql 8, setting a variable in a select is deprecated (though it still works for now) and you should do `select row_number() over () as pseudo_row_rum` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySqls parser expects there something else, so name the table

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS pseudo_row_num,mytable.* FROM myTable;
```